# PWA Worker throws an error with AngularDart

Tags: dart, service-worker, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am trying to add offline capabilities to an angular dart project, running `pub build` but

```
Running pub build:pub.exe build
-----
Unhandled exception:
ProcessException: The system cannot find the file specified.
Command: pub.exe build
#0      _buildProjectIfEmptyOrOld (http://localhost:52940/pwa.dart:116)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      main (http://localhost:52940/pwa.dart:40)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-
patch/isolate_patch.dart:263)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-
patch/isolate_patch.dart:151)
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:my_app/views/app_component/app_component.dart';
import 'package:pwa/client.dart' as pwa;

void main() {
    bootstrap(AppComponent);

    // register PWA ServiceWorker for offline caching.
    new pwa.Client();
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
     pwa: ^0.1.2
```

Comment: Where did you put the `pwa.dart` file? Did you check the examples https://github.com/isoos/pwa/tree/master/examples ?

Comment: According to the article I was trying to know how to do that, link: http://news.dartlang.org/2017/03/making-dart-web-app-offline-capable-3.html

Comment: The article shows adding the dependencies will auto generate the required files, but it doesn't, even after adding it manually with the help of examples also throws the same error.

Comment: https://github.com/isoos/pwa/tree/master/examples/pwa_defaults says you need to run `pub run pwa`

Comment: Running pub run pwa throws the same error.

Comment: I guess it's a Windows-related issue. Try to execute `pub.exe` manually or try to figure out if there is a `pub.exe` on your disk and if it's covered with the systems `PATH` variable. I haven't used Dart on Windows myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

At that point, the `pwa` is trying to run `pub.exe build`. I haven't tried it on Windows, only a friend reported it working, but it is entirely possible that `pub.exe` does no longer work (if it ever did), and it should have been `pub` all along (and in this case it is a Windows-related bug).

Suggested workaround:

- run `pub build`
- run `pub run pwa`
- run `pub build` again

If the above works, let me know, and I'll fix it in a patch release.

Comment: yes the error still persist, while running pub run pwa

Comment: the error still persist  in the dependency  update `pwa 0.1.7` while running `pub run pwa` on windows.